# Trouble with "Keyboard Failure" on Dell PowerEdge R410

Tags: centos6, dell-poweredge, keyboard

I own some Dell PowerEdge Servers. One of these servers is a R410 which has some problems at the moment. I have already sent the server in the datacenter and tried to make a remote installation via Lantronix KVM. The first time, all ran fine. I installed CentOS 6 and then SolusVM with the requisite kernel modules. After I installed the SolusVM I made a system reboot and the server gives me a "Kernel Panic" message and I can't use the keyboard. So I use a PDU to disconnect the server from the power station, it works. After I connected the server to the PDU and started it up,  it went on into the normal Dell boot montior but didn't load the full boot setup... In the BIOS startup, it gives the following message: "**Testing Memory. Please Wait. Keyboard Failure.**"

Now I can't use the KVM keyboard or enter the BIOS setup. I have no control over my server. Do you maybe have a solution, which problem this could be?

Comment: Did you try using an actual keyboard connected to the server?

Comment: No, i only try it with the Lantronix KVM.

Comment: You don't have an iDrac on this server ?

Comment: No. Because i have no iDRAC on this server i use temporary a Lantronix KVM but this is the problem, at this time it's not working.